# Able to set only background color but not background image

Tags: html, css

Suddenly background is not visible in my Chrome. I am able to set only background color but not background image. Why is this happening suddenly?

```css
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("images/smile.jpg");
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Could you let me know your folder structure?

Answer (score -1):

**Try to replace address of image in background-image as following manner -**

```
("../images/smile.jpg")
```

Comment: Yeahhh!!! i got it thank you.can you tell me what is the difference btw "images/xxx.jpg" and "../images/xx.jpg"

Comment: the manner "../image/xx.jpg" find your xx named image in image folder from any location in your solution while in the manner "image/xx.jpg " will be found only when your image and your html file exist in same folder